# Some properties of l-bisimulation

Tags: logic, model-theory, modal-logic

In Martin Otto's paper "Elementary proof of Van Benthem-Rosen Characterisation Theorem" I've found this lemma:

Lemma 2.1. Over the class of all Kripke structures of a finite fixed relational type:

(i) $\sim_{l}$ has finite index

(ii) $\mathfrak{A},a\sim_{l}\mathfrak{B},b$ iff $a\in\mathfrak{A}$ and $b\in\mathfrak{B}$ are indistinguishable in $ML_{l}$

(iii) each $\sim_{l}$ equivalence class is definable by an $ML_{l}$ formula.

$\sim_{l}$ stands for l-bisimulation, and $ML_{l}$ stands for all formulas of propositional modal logic which have modal depth at most $l$. Furthermore, Otto says that this lemma is consequence of Ehrenfeucht - Fraisse analysis of bisimulation game. Does anyone can recommend some book where I can find proof for this lemma or offer any hint? I understand what bisimulation game is, but I have trouble understanding what is l-bisimulation and its relation to ordinary bisimulation.

Comment: Can you give us a link to Otto's paper ?

Comment: It is available here www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~otto/papers/vBRnote04.ps in PostScriptum format

Comment: You can find a proof of the same lemma for first-order logic in this book: http://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540004288. I don't think the proofs will be very different.

Comment: $l$-bisimulation is just bisimulation that is restricted to depth $l$. So if $a$ and $b$ are not bisimilar, but they can only be distinguished after $l + 1$ steps, then they are still $l$-bisimilar.

Answer (score 2):

The entry *Model Theory of Modal Logic* by Valentin Goranko and Martin Otto in *[Handbook of Modal Logic](https://www.elsevier.com/books/handbook-of-modal-logic/blackburn/978-0-444-51690-9)*, Blackburn, van Benthem and Wolter (eds.), Elsevier 2007 covers this territory.

A [final draft of the chapter](http://www2.philosophy.su.se/goranko/papers/Handbook%20Modal%20Logic%20-%20Model%20Theory%20of%20Modal%20Logic-%20final%20draft%20060418.pdf) may be downloaded from [Goranko's website](http://www2.philosophy.su.se/goranko/publications.htm).